# XLinq with encrypted files?

Tags: xml, encryption, linq-to-xml, xml-literals

How do I create/read/write XLinq and/or [VB XML Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364068(VS.80).aspx#vb9overview_topic6) from and to encrypted xml files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just load XML to memory, decrypt it and then do whatever you like. There is no way of direct manipulation of already encrypted XML without prior decryption because this just negates encryption at all.

Comment: Sound good to me.
Any technical advice will be really appreciated.
Also, what about when (I don't, but if I will) I have large files, should this be the same behavior?

Comment: LINQ cannot operate on incomplete or lazy-loaded XML files. So, in any case you will have to load a file to memory and decrypt it before. If you will find some way for LINQ to operate on files only partially loaded into memory, then you can consider using TrueCrypt for example to place unencrypted files into encrypted storage container

Comment: Please elaborate more about that TrueCrypt thing.
Besides, what would be called a 'large' file that I have to consider partial loading?

Comment: www.truecrypt.org - it is a software to create secret encrypted files, that can be mounted as disks into Windows.